# Does Google Drive API have a api to show the upgrade link?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does Google Drive API have an api to show the storage upgrade link?

I mean a link which can let user to buy more space.

Like Google One, https://one.google.com/plans

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any response from the Drive API that returns Drive Plans information and/or URL for it. However if it helps in your use case, Drive API method [about.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) returns storage quota information. Can I have more details on the use case? Why not just use this URL instead of making a call to API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google drive api is a file storage api.   It gives you access to the data beind the google drive web application.  It does not give you any control over the google drive web application itself.

Upgrade storage link is outside the scope for this api.